# Make sure that the default admin$ share is enable on ServerName

Tags: installation, remote-debugging, remote-access, psexec

When running the psexec command to remotely install or execute something on a sever on the same network the following error was displayed.

**Couldn't access ServerName**

**The network name cannot be found**

**Make sure that the default admin$ share is enable on ServerName**

Most references suggested that you add the following to the registry, but in my case this was already added to the server. This did not resolve the issue.

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System
and create or modify a REG_DWORD value LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy and set its value to 1

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15906536/psexec-giving-the-system-cannot-find-the-file-specified

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Solution:

You need to add the 'admin$' share which is your **C:\Windows** location.

1. Go to `C:\windows` and right-click --> `Properties`
2. Hit `advance sharing`
3. Click the check box `Share this folder`
4. Enter the name `admin$` and hit Permissions
5. I would recommend removing 'Everyone' and adding just the users that the PsExec command will use to execute.

Run the PsExec command again and this should resolve your issue.

**Edit:**

You can also turn on your AutoShareServer in the registry, which will automatically create the admin shares.

1. Start regisry `regedit`
2. Search for key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanServer\Parameters\AutoShareServer`
3. Change the `AutoShareServer` key to `1`

Comment: while giving share name as `admin$` it is throwing error as reserved names!

Comment: Another solution is to turn on your Auto Share Server setting in the registry.  See edited Answer

Comment: The server I'm working on (AWS EC2 Win2016) does not have that key at HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanServer\Parameters\

Comment: A Windows 10 1903 VM didn't like option 1. When I went back and looked it says the directory was not shared.

Answer (score 3):

You can also enable amins$ share by enabling **File and Printer Sharing (SMB-In)** Firewall Rule.

Go to `Control Panel > System ans Security > Windows Defender Firewall > Advance Settings > Inbound Rules`. Right click on **File and Printer Sharing (SMB-In)** from the list and select Enable Rule`. Normally, there are two File and Printer Sharing (SMB-In), one is for **Domain profile** and one is for **Public & Private profile**. I'm not sure which profile should be applied, Domain or Public or Private. For me, it's Domain profile.

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was a network problem like mentioned in the error message.

I needed to allow SMB traffic on port 445 on the target machine. PSExec worked straight away after adding the firewall rule to allow that traffic.