# Running psexec on Windows Server 2008 R2 from Windows 7

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-server-2008-r2, psexec, sysinternals

I'm trying to successfully run a batch file located on a server pc (Windows Server 2008 R2) from my Windows 7 client PC. But its not working and the command prompt shows the following error information message.

When I run

```
psexec \\199.219.21.141 -u admin /c "C:\Compile.bat"
```

I'm prompted for password, and when I enter the password and press  I get

```
Make sure that the default admin$ share is enabled on 199.219.21.141
```

(which is my machine ipaddress)

The user **admin** is part of the Local administrators on the server machine

Things I tried,

1. Turning off the UAC Turning OFF the Windows Firewall
2. Setting the **LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy** DWORD to 1 in, HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System
3. Caching the user credentials using

cmdkey.exe /add:MACHINE_NAME_HERE /user:199.219.21.141\admin /pass:PASSWORD_HERE 
psexec.exe \199.219.21.141 -i notepad
cmdkey.exe /delete:199.219.21.141

After trying to connect for some time, it again displays

```
 Make sure that the default admin$ share is enabled on 199.219.21.141
```

Any ideas what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What about [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18388381/make-sure-that-the-default-admin-share-is-enable-on-servername)?

Comment: Also see Mark Russinovich's article on [PsExec](http://windowsitpro.com/systems-management/psexec). The last paragraph outlines, how the tool is implemented. With that information, you will see, when and why you get the error message you get.

Comment: Are you *sure* you turned the firewall off on the server?

Comment: @HarryJohnston : Yes I did

Comment: @wOxxOm : Yes, I even have a admin share created for C:\Windows folder with Read/Write/Execute access given for the user who executes PsExec command from a client PC

Comment: What happens if the user says `dir \\server\admin$` ?

Comment: @HarryJohnston : I get the same error, Make sure that default admin$ share is enabled

Comment: @HarryJohnston : Works fine when I run the commands between two Windows 7 machines. But doesn't work when Win 2008 server comes into picture

Comment: *"Make sure that default admin$ share is enabled"* is not an error message of the `dir` command. HarryJohnston suggested you run `dir \\server\admin$` on **your** machine, without `PsExec`, to diagnose, whether the admin$ share is accessible on the remote machine.

Comment: I get Error: The network path was not found.Although the same format on Windows 7 machine works perfectly.

Comment: So in other words: The admin$ share is inaccessible. Either it doesn't exist, or it isn't accessible for a number of other reasons. For example: [Can't connect to default admin share on Windows 2008](http://serverfault.com/q/38999).

Comment: Can you ping the server?

Comment: Yea I thought so. The admin$ share is not accessible and via ping it works just fine. I have to restart the server or something. Not sure

Comment: I can see the files listed if I run the \\IPaddress\ShareName$